# Actions must be plain objects while using redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am implementing asynchronous action creators using react-redux and redux-thunk. However, I am getting the following error message: Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I know that actions are supposed to be plain objects, and that middleware like thunk is supposed to take care of the cases when they are not. I have read several tutorials and looked at **every** SO question I could find on this, but I still can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Am I setting up thunk incorrectly, or am I using action creators in a bad way? Might this be an error with webpack or something?

Below I've included the code snippets I believe are relevant. Please let me know if additional info is needed.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer   from './reducers';
import Layout    from './components/Layout.js';
import OrderPage from './containers/order-page';


const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App>
            <Route  exact path="/" component={Layout}/>
        </App>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('.app'));
```

**reducers/order.js**

```
import { FETCH_ERR, FETCH_SUCCESS, START_FETCH } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  fetching: false
};

export default (state=initialState, action)=>{
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_FETCH: 
      return {
        fetching: true
      }
    case FETCH_ERR:
      return {
        err: action.payload.err,
        fetching: false
      }
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        price: action.payload,
        fetching: false
      }
    default:
        return state
  }

}
```

**actions/price-fetch.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const FETCH_ERR = 'FETCH_ERR'
const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS'
const START_FETCH  = 'START_FETCH'


const fetchSucc = (data)=>{
  return{
    type:FETCH_SUCCESS,
    payload:data
  }
}

const fetchFail = (message)=>{
  return{
    type:FETCH_ERR,
    payload:message
  }
}

const startFetch = () =>{
  return{
    type: START_FETCH,
    payload:null
  }
}

const fetchPrices = () =>{
  return async (dispatch) =>{
    try {
      dispatch(startFetch())
      let data = await axios.get('mybackendurl')
      dispatch(fetchSucc(data))
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchFail({err:'failed to get shit'}))
    }
  }
}

export {
    FETCH_ERR,
    FETCH_SUCCESS,
    fetchPrices,
    START_FETCH
}
```

**Relevant pieces of containers/order.js**

```
import React, { Component }     from 'react';

import { connect }                      from 'react-redux';

import { fetchPrices }          from '../actions/price-fetch';

class Order extends Component {


...



  render() {
    this.props.fetchPrices();
    return ...

  }


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchPrice: () => {
      dispatch(fetchPrices())
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        prices: state.order
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Order);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone comes across the same issue. The problem was not in the code shown above, or how I was dispatching actions. I had a duplicate definition of the redux-store in a different file, which overwrote the definition with the middleware.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the action declaration like below, due to which it was throwing such error.

```
export const withdrawMoney = (amount) => {
return (dispath) => {
    dispath({
        type: "withdraw",
        payload: amount
    })
}};
```

What I did was just changed my action definition to be an object type

```
export const depositMoney = (amount) => ({
   type: "deposit",
   payload: amount
});
```

And it jsut worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is here grasping at straws when using ImmutableJS + Typescript, turns out that you HAVE to define the "initialState" for the middleware to actually apply.

```
export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({APIReducer}),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may be because you have an `async (dispatch)` function. That would cause it to return a `Promise`, which may be even confusing `thunk`.

In normal scenarios, the function itself would return another function, which `thunk` would inject the `dispatch` and call again and you would call `dispatch` inside the function:

```
arg => dispatch => dispatch({ type: arg });
```

When you add `async`, it basically becomes the same as this:

```
arg => dispatch => Promise.resolve(dispatch({ type: arg }));
```

You may have to ditch `async/await` inside of there and just use `axios` as a normal `Promise`, or add something extra to ensure it returns a nothing instead of a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchPrices = () =>{`
 return async (dispatch) =>{`
 try {
   dispatch(startFetch())
   let data = await axios.get('mybackendurl')
   dispatch(fetchSucc(data))
 } catch (error) {
   dispatch(fetchFail({err:'failed to get shit'}))
  }
 }
}
```

is returning a promise so when you do

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
       return {
    fetchPrice: () => {
      dispatch(fetchPrices())
    }
  }
}
```

`dispatch(fetchPrices())` is getting a promise not a **plain** object

the way i do these things is leave the heavy weight to my action; call async, when resolved dispatch data to store and in your component listen for and handle data(prices list) change.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchPrice
  }
}
```

you can thus show "loading please wait" while price list is empty and promise is not resolved/rejected